# Pandas pricing statistics

Tags: pandas

There's got to be a pandas dataframe way to approach this problem other than iterating over loops...

Given a set of list prices that can change sporadically over time (as many as 70 times in a quarter but at a date only, no time), including price increases and decreases, I'm looking for the start price, end price, max price, min price, mean price, and the price 45 days into the quarter.

```
list_prices = [
    {'product': 'prodA', 'price': 68.40, 'eff_date': '2016-12-01'},
    {'product': 'prodA', 'price': 69.50, 'eff_date': '2017-02-17'},
    {'product': 'prodB', 'price': 34.20, 'eff_date': '2015-10-18'},
    {'product': 'prodB', 'price': 32.55, 'eff_date': '2016-01-07'},
    {'product': 'prodC', 'price': 19.95, 'eff_date': '2017-03-01'},
    ]
```

And computing for 2017Q1,

```
  quarter product start    end    min    max      mean  day45
0   prodA  2017Q1  68.4   69.5   68.4   69.5  68.92556   68.4
1   prodB  2017Q1  32.2  32.55   34.2  32.55     32.66  32.55
2   prodC  2017Q1   NaN  19.95  19.95  19.95     19.95    NaN
```

Results are computed for 4 quarters at a time, so the result is a matrix of prod, qtr as row indices and start, end, min, max, mean, mid

Resample with OHLC would work for but haven't found the right technique when the date is outside the quarter's dates.

So... is there a pandorable way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_prices)

# convert eff_date to datetime object
df['eff_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['eff_date'])

# set eff_date as index. helps with grouping by quarter
df.set_index('eff_date', inplace=True)

def get_metrics(x):

    # start of the quarter
    start = x.iloc[0]

    # end of the quarter
    end = x.iloc[-1]

    # middle of the quarter
    mid_date_index = int(len(x)/2)
    mid = x.iloc[mid_date_index]

    max = x.max()
    min = x.min()
    mean = x.mean()

    return pd.Series({'max': max, 'min': min, 'mean': mean, 'start': start, 'end': end, 'mid': mid})

# groupby product and quarter and get all the metrics
df.groupby(['product', pd.TimeGrouper('Q')])['price'].apply(get_metrics).unstack()
```